# Is it possible to extract game's specific data using steam API?

Tags: json, api, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am new to Json and API.

But, for study now I am figuring out how to get specific game data from steam API.

I followed lots of process.. and get api code from steam.

At first, I thought that 'oh I can extract all of game data using my API code!'

but,,, there's a question.

Most of the JSON QUERY requires my API code.

But they print just single result (especially about certain ID)

I want to know about what game is best selling or played..

like the steamspy : http://steamspy.com/

But the steam API just offers only user stat and so on.

At this point, now I am highlight again. I am new to Json.

so.. I wonder, "Is it possible to extract game's specific data using steam API?"

Not the single user's data.

But the all of the game's list.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have done little research but I know you can colllect the game-names from Steam also the ID:s I 
by using

http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/

I believe then you can filtering with different criterias some stuff.

regarding the **Steamspy**

This may not answer the full question but why don't you just using Steamspys:s API

you can collect most played games:

http://steamspy.com/api.php

```
 ### genre ###

  Returns games in this particular genre. Requires *genre* parameter and works like this:

  * steamspy.com/api.php?request=genre&genre=Early+Access

  ### top100in2weeks ###

  Returns Top 100 games by players in the last two weeks.

  ### top100forever ###

  Returns Top 100 games by players since March 2009.

  ### top100owned ###

  Returns Top 100 games by owners.

  ### all ###

  Returns all games with owners data sorted by owners.
```

I hope this is to some help

Best regards
Xsi